# Javascript/PHP countdown timer stops at a certain time?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have this code for a countdown timer. its basically a combination of PHP/Javascript countdown timer which will gets the `$end_date` from a Mysql table/field.

The problem is that it will stop automatically (which is unwanted) at a certain time.

For example: I set the `$end_date` to `September 19 2013 11:30:00 AM GMT` in mysql database.

the countdown starts and works fine and starts counting down as it should. However, when the countdown timer reaches `September 19 2013 13:00:00 PM GMT` it will stop and it will show the Times Up message! Basically it will stop working or counting down once the `$end_date` has been changed to `13:00:00 PM`.

I cannot see anything in my code that will cause this issue. apart from this line:

```
if ($now < $exp_date ) {
?>
```

but again, this line only tells the script when to start counting and as far i can see it shouldn't stop the countdown timer to stop as long as the timer has not reached the `$end_date`. or am I missing something?

here is my code:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
<?php date_default_timezone_set('GMT'); ?>
<?php
session_start();
// Run a select query to get my letest 6 items
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "config/connect.php";
$dynamicList = "";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM item ORDER BY id";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $date_added = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
             $end_date = date("F d Y H:i:s A T", strtotime($row["end_date"]));
             $price = $row["price"];
             $dynamicList .= '<div>' . $end_date . '
      </div>';
    }
} else {
    $dynamicList = "No Records";
}
?>

<?php
$date = $end_date;
$exp_date = strtotime($date);
$now = time();

if ($now < $exp_date ) {
?>
<script>
// Count down milliseconds = server_end - server_now = client_end - client_now
var server_end = <?php echo $exp_date; ?> * 1000;
var server_now = <?php echo time(); ?> * 1000;
var client_now = new Date().getTime();
var end = server_end - server_now + client_now; // this is the real end time

var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;
var _day = _hour *24
var timer;

function showRemaining()
{
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = end - now;
    if (distance < 0 ) {
       clearInterval( timer );
       document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

       return;
    }
    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    var hours = Math.floor( (distance % _day ) / _hour );
    var minutes = Math.floor( (distance % _hour) / _minute );
    var seconds = Math.floor( (distance % _minute) / _second );

    var countdown = document.getElementById('countdown');
    countdown.innerHTML = '';
   if (days) {
        countdown.innerHTML += 'Days: ' + days + '<br />';
    }
    countdown.innerHTML += 'Hours: ' + hours+ '<br />';
    countdown.innerHTML += 'Minutes: ' + minutes+ '<br />';
    countdown.innerHTML += 'Seconds: ' + seconds+ '<br />';
}

timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
</script>
<?php
} else {
    echo "Times Up";
}
?>
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's no such time as 13 pm.

Comment: @Juhana, are you sure? because i echo the result on my page and i get this echo-ed there: September 19 2013 13:00:00 PM GMT ... where did you get that idea from that there is no such time as 13 PM?

Comment: What exactly are you echoing? What time do you expect 13 pm to be? My clock has only 12 hours.

Comment: @Juhana, i am echoing `<?php echo $end_date; ?>`.

Comment: @Juhana, 13 PM is one o'clock in the afternoon. I Can't believe I am talking about what 13 PM is!!

Comment: `H` is the signifier for hours in a 24-hour clock. You need `h` if you use 12-hour clock.

Comment: One o'clock in the afternoon is 1 PM. It seems that you're completely confusing 24-hour and 12-hour formats.

Comment: @Juhana, Thanks ever so much mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`13:00:00 PM` is not a valid time. `AM` and `PM` are used to indicate which side of the 12-hour cycle the time is. You cannot logically say you're on the 13th hour of the 12 hour side of the clock.

**EDIT:** For clarity: 13:00 == 1 PM, 13:00 PM == nothing.

Comment: so how come my PC is showing my time as 13:15 now? this doesn't make sense.

Comment: That is right. But it has no PM or AM on the end, this is the major problem. Please read my answer carefully.

Comment: And to say 13 PM would mean you were saying 13 hours after midday, which means it'd be referring to 1 AM or 01:00 and not 1 PM or 13:00.

Comment: OMG, mate, I can't believe it was only that. I can't believe I didn't know that. I just removed the `H` and it started working again! I appreciate it.